# SwapExactTokensForTokens gives error "replacement transaction underpriced"

Tags: solidity, python

I try to buy tokens in python script(SwapExactETHForTokens). When I buy a token and approve it, everything is working well, but when I try to swap an already approved  token into another token(SwapExactTokensForTokens) it gives me

> raise ValueError(response["error"])
> ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'replacement transaction underpriced'}

But when I comment the SwapExactETHForTokens function and run only SwapExactTokensForTokens
it working well.

```
def swap_tokens_for_tokens(contract,coin_1, coin_2):
    tokens_for_tokens = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(
    1000000000000000000, 0, [coin_1, coin_2],
    config.wallet_address,
    (int(time.time()) + 100000)
    ).buildTransaction({
    'from': config.wallet_address,
    'value': web3.toWei('0.1', 'ether'),  # This is the Token(BNB) amount you want to Swap from
    'gas': 25000000,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei('10', 'gwei'),
    'nonce': config.nonce,
    })
```

Comment: Hi KhachaturKhachatryan! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! How is `config.nonce` calculated? Do you increase it between transactions?

Comment: Hi Ismael, thank you.
nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address)

Comment: Why I need to increase nonce?

Comment: The nonce starts with 0, then it increase by 1 for each transaction. If you use the same nonce the system will think you are trying to replace a transaction.

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my issue.